# Static Block for specific products in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, static-block

Is there any way to do this :

I have two kinds of products, Handmade and ready women accessories. for handmade products I want a block under the price that tell the customer "This Product is 100% Handmade" and for the ready product nothing. So it will be only for the Handmade.

I already have a block but it is visible to all products, so I want it to be visible only for Handmade products.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an attribute called `handmade` as a `yes/no` type and based on that data, display either the relevant text or the static block:

```
if($product->getHandmade()){
    echo $this->__("This Product is 100% Handmade");
}
```

To create the attribute go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Add New Attribute` and create it with the following parameters:

[image]

Make sure that the Frontend properties dropdown for **Visibile on Product Page** is set to "Yes"

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to set 'Visible on product View Page on Frontend' to 'Yes'? This will make it appear in the 'Additional information' section. Even if you set this to 'No' it will still be loaded on the product page. The rest of the solution looks OK...so +1

Comment: Thank seems great, ill do it and let you know the results!

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you want it in additional information?

Comment: Can you please explain this part : based on that data, display either the relevant text or the static block:

if($product->getHandmade()){
    echo $this->__("This Product is 100% Handmade");
}

Comment: this is the blcok that already shown in product page :              <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
        <?php if ($block_detail_product_page_1 = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_detail_product_page_1')->toHtml()): ?>
         <?php echo $block_detail_product_page_1; ?>
        <?php endif;?>

Comment: Put the `if` code after `getChildHtml('other')` block, then. You'll have to go into your product and set the flag equal to "yes" for handmade before anything will actually show up.

Comment: im not expert, i got this "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting" can you please guide me ?

Comment: You need to place it after the semicolon. You should also learn some PHP - it's helpful when debugging Magento.

Comment: here is the original copy file if u want to edit it http://www.glittercorner.com/view.phtml

Comment: @hani This is the only time I will ever do this. You should pay a developer to help you in the future -- Magento.SE isn't for requesting free contract work: https://gist.github.com/philwinkle/70259653cae3cfe43ada

Comment: Thank you very much i really appreciate it :), it works great. im trying now to make it instead of echo $this->__("This Product is 100% Handmade");  TO <p class="handmade"><?php echo $block_detail_product_page_1;?></p> , as i want the text of This product is 100%..etc to be bold and red.

Comment: You're welcome - glad to see you expanding on the direction. Cheers.

Comment: I did the following improvements to the code and its perfect now!: <?php if($_product->getHandmade()):?>
<p class="handmade"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_detail_product_page_1')->toHtml(); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>   , im sorry i dont know how to use comment codes .

Comment: It's worth noting that _$product->getHandmade() is a method generated automatically as a result of adding the attribute. And, that $_product was $product in the original answer. Plus this line in view.phtml

$_product = $this->getProduct();